# Xamarin Android Layout button event not triggering

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, mono, xamarin

i have a question about my XAMARIN C# android project
currently i have this issue my code:

```
  [Activity(Label = "Dashboard")]
public class Index : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Index);
        Button Contact = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnContact);
        Contact.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
             StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(Contact)));
             //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Contact);
        };

    }
```

}

I created a button in Index.axml and its referenced in the XML of Index.axml but the

```
Contact.Click += (sender, e) => {};
```

is not fireing does someone know what i missed or forgot i dont see the problem ?

Comment: Did you try to run a default project? It's the same...

Comment: And what about breakpoints? Did you try them? Maybe exception occurs in StartActivity(new Intent(this, typeof(Contact)))..

Comment: It dont event trigger the button event

Comment: hey, did you get anywhere on this?

Comment: @StefanvandeLaarschot Can you post your solution here please. It might be helpful to others with similar problems.